# Transfer data from iphone to Windows PC

Tags: c#, ios, tcp, bluetooth, wifi

I am looking to transfer data from my iPhone app using bluetooth, bonjour or wifi to my Windows PC to an app written in C#. The data consists of an array of strings.

So my question is, how do I go about transferring data to a windows PC from the standard iPhone APIs.

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect you know better than to ask a "give me teh codez" so could you show what you have tried? BTW, using wifi TCP might be a good option.

Comment: I've looked at the Bonjour windows SDK - there is almost no documentation on that. I actually have no idea how to set up a TCP connection over wifi so that would be a good place to give me a suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Create a socket in C# that listens on some port. Connect to that IP with the device and send data as much as you want. Might require port forwarding if using external IP's.

Comment: Look at the `TCPClient` class documentation for how to do TCP comms in .NET. Doing it over wifi is no different than a standard network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have iPhone so I am not sure if iPhone can use Bonjour to propagate its' services in the local network. If it does:

1. First if you don't want to enter ip manually and port of your iPhone you need to discover ip and port(or set it on both sides to const value) through Bonjour SDK for Windows: https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html then add reference to your project inside visual studio and scan local network for your device.
2. You need to write service for your iPhone which is TCP client waiting for incoming traffic from PC( don't know Objective-C) and get PC's ip and port in local area network.
3. Send the data to PC and receive it by TCP client on PC side.

PC side is around 200-300 lines of code, don't know about iPhone side.

And yes this is true there is no documentation at all and this one which is there is not readable for humans : P. It takes few days to sort it out.